# How to merge and group data into conditional chunks in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that i am trying to merge in a certain way. They are below:

df_A

```
    time expression_w expression_h
     0      neutral      neutral
     1      neutral      neutral
     2      neutral      neutral
     3      neutral      neutral
     4      neutral      neutral
     5      neutral      neutral
     6      neutral      neutral
     7      neutral      neutral
     8      neutral      neutral
     9      neutral      neutral
    10      neutral      neutral
    11      neutral      neutral
    12      neutral      neutral
    13      neutral      neutral
    14      neutral      neutral
    15      neutral      neutral
    16      neutral      neutral
    17      neutral      neutral
    18      neutral      neutral
    19      neutral      neutral
```

and df_B:

```
   start   stop
  12.12  12.47
  13.44  20.82
```

I want to merge `df_A.expression_w` and `df_A.expression_h` based on `df_A.time` onto df_B only when `df_A.time` is in between `df_B.start` and `df_B.stop`. The aggregation statistic should be MODE.

It should look like this:

```
   start   stop expression_w  expression_h
  12.12  12.47      neutral     neutral
  13.44  20.82      neutral     neutral
```

#### If I extend the dataframe to

df_A

```
    time expression_w expression_h
     0      neutral      neutral
     1      neutral      neutral
     2      neutral      neutral
     3      neutral      neutral
     4      neutral      neutral
     5      neutral      neutral
     6      neutral      neutral
     7      neutral      neutral
     8      neutral      neutral
     9      neutral      neutral
    10      neutral      neutral
    11      neutral      neutral
    12      neutral      neutral
    13      neutral      neutral
    14      neutral      neutral
    15      neutral      neutral
    16      neutral      neutral
    17      neutral      neutral
    18      neutral      neutral
    19      neutral      neutral
    20      neutral      neutral
    21      neutral      neutral
    22      neutral      neutral
    23      neutral      neutral
    24      neutral      neutral
    25      neutral      neutral
    26      neutral      neutral
    27      neutral      neutral
    28      neutral      neutral
    29      neutral      neutral
    30      neutral      neutral
    31      neutral      neutral
    32      neutral      neutral
    33      neutral      neutral
    34      neutral      neutral
    35      neutral      neutral
    36      neutral      neutral
    37      neutral      neutral
    38      neutral      neutral
    39      neutral      neutral
    30      neutral      neutral
    41      neutral      neutral
    42      neutral      neutral
    43      neutral      neutral
    44      neutral      neutral
    45      neutral      neutral
    46      neutral      neutral
    47      neutral      neutral
    48      neutral      neutral
    49      neutral      neutral
    50      neutral      neutral
```

and

```
    start   stop
0  12.12  12.47
1  13.44  20.82
2  20.88  29.63
3  31.61  33.33
4  33.44  42.21
```

The code recommended below breaks and gives this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-117-47594fba3999> in <module>
      1 # df_B= d_s[['start', 'stop']].head(3)
      2 # df_A = df.head(500)
----> 3 y = (df_B.assign(dummy=1, idx=np.arange(df_B.shape[1]))
      4     .merge(df_A.assign(dummy=1), on='dummy')
      5     .query('start<=time<=stop')

~/anaconda3/envs/cv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in assign(self, **kwargs)
   3687 
   3688         for k, v in kwargs.items():
-> 3689             data[k] = com.apply_if_callable(v, data)
   3690         return data
   3691 

~/anaconda3/envs/cv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3035         else:
   3036             # set column
-> 3037             self._set_item(key, value)
   3038 
   3039     def _setitem_slice(self, key: slice, value):

~/anaconda3/envs/cv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3111         """
   3112         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 3113         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   3114         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3115 

~/anaconda3/envs/cv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
   3756 
   3757             # turn me into an ndarray
-> 3758             value = sanitize_index(value, self.index)
   3759             if not isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, Index)):
   3760                 if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0:

~/anaconda3/envs/cv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in sanitize_index(data, index)
    746     if len(data) != len(index):
    747         raise ValueError(
--> 748             "Length of values "
    749             f"({len(data)}) "
    750             "does not match length of index "

ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (5)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try a cross merge and query

```
(df_B.assign(dummy=1, idx=np.arange(len(df_B))
    .merge(df_A.assign(dummy=1), on='dummy')
    .query('start<=time<=stop')
    .drop('dummy',axis=1)
    .groupby('idx', as_index=False)
    .agg(pd.Series.mode)
)
```

Output (note that there are no `time` between `start` and `stop` for the first row):

```
   idx  start   stop expression_w expression_h
0    1  13.44  20.82      neutral      neutral
```

Comment: Why does it break when I extend the dataframe? See edit.

Comment: @connor449 sorry, I messed up `idx`, should just be `len(df_B)`. See updates